# "attempt to index a nil value"-error in Lua

Tags: lua

```
function newImage(Image, posx, posy)
    pic = Bitmap.new(Texture.new(Image))
    stage:addChild(pic)
    pic:setPosition(posx,posy)
end

local birdie = newImage("bird.png", 100, 100)
birdie:setAnchorPoint(0.5,0.5)
birdie:setRotation(45)
```

If I call `newImage()` like above, the image gets loaded but when I try to use `birdie:setAnchorpoint()` it gives the error "attempt to index birdie, a nil value".
How can I fix this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You're not returning anything from your function call. Also, use `local` variables inside functions.

```
function newImage(Image, posx, posy)
    local pic = Bitmap.new(Texture.new(Image)) 
    stage: addChild(pic)
    pic:setPosition(posx,posy)
    return pic
end
```